# python cannot import graph-tool after installing it on a mac using brew (homebrew)

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, python-import, graph-tool

I used homebrew to install graph-tool on a macOS 10.14 using the command `brew install graph-tool`, but I cannot import it in python (that is installed through anaconda in `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`). How can I make Python able to import graph-tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Prefer Conda Packages

If you want to use something in a Conda environment, then the best practice is to install through Conda. In this case, the `graph-tool` package is available through [Conda Forge](https://conda-forge.org/) and can be installed with

```
conda install -c conda-forge graph-tool
```

Personally, since I started using Conda in 2016, I've found no reason to use Homebrew or MacPorts. There might be some exceptions, but this package isn't one.

---

#### `conda install` not working

Sometimes the packages you already have installed can conflict with the ones you want to add. This is especially the case when it comes to massive envs like the **base** in Anaconda. Best practice for using Conda is to avoid installing in **base** and instead create envs for each project or project type. This also helps you avoid breaking code you've already written because sometimes installs can trigger a version change in a package you were using.

In this case, you could make a new env, say `foo`, with

```
conda create --name foo -c conda-forge graph-tool
```

You can list any additional packages you know you'll need after `graph-tool`.

Comment: For some reason also `conda install` seems to make some problems on my machine... it seems to get stuck on this stage: `$ conda install -c conda-forge graph-tool
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: / `

Comment: @Ohm yeah, the Anaconda **base** env can sometimes be troublesome to manipulate. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much - finally I understand why it is wise to create a new environment in such a case, your explanation was clear and sound.